# Get real IP in symfony

Tags: symfony1, ip-address

I want to kown how I can get the real IP of a client on Symfony framework

I know a function which can get it :

```
    if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))
    {
     //check for ip from share internet
     $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
    {
     // Check for the Proxy User
     $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    }
    else
    {
     $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
```

Actually I use this on symfony, but it's not the reallity :

```
    sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest()->getHttpHeader('addr', 'remote');
```

I'm on Symfony 1.0.22

Comment: The short answer is that you can't (with any technology) if the client doesn't want it and takes appropriate actions.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to use a Symfony wrapper for such a trivial bit of functionality?

BTW - anyone can inject additional headers in the request - but spoofing a client IP address takes a bit more work. So the method you are using is trivial to spoof. Symfony has no magic mojo to get around this.

Comment: Because "Symfony is an object-oriented framework, and the use of PHP's super globals is strongly discouraged."
https://insight.sensiolabs.com/what-we-analyse/symfony.use_super_globals